# mysql query for the latest 10 results in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

okay, my problem is a little bit more difficult than the title would tell...

i have a table with messages, i load all these messages in php using a while loop.

my sql query looks like this at the moment:

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM messages 
 WHERE thread_id = '" . $thread_id . "'
 ORDER BY date_sent"
```

works fine and returns all the messages after one another, so that i have the latest message at the bottom (which is important, since my messaging module works like facebook, with a small reply field at the bottom, to let the users chat directly)

now, what i'd like to have is a query that would give me only the latest 10 results in a single query.

i already have the number of wanted results ($number_of_results = 10;)

it'd be really cool, if i didn't have to count the rows of the result first, but rather would request the result in a single query.

something like:

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM messages 
 WHERE thread_id = '" . $thread_id . "'
 ORDER BY date_sent 
 LIMIT TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_ROWS_WHERE_THREAD_ID_IS_MY_THREAD_ID-$number_of_results, $number_of_results"
```

is there a way to do something like this...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM messages 
 WHERE thread_id = '" . $thread_id . "' 
 ORDER BY date_sent DESC 
 LIMIT 10";
```

Make sure you have this index

```sql
ALTER TABLE messages 
ADD INDEX threadid_datesent_ndx( thread_id, date_sent );
```

If you want the 10 reversed again, then do this:

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM
 (
     SELECT * 
     FROM messages 
     WHERE thread_id = '" . $thread_id . "' 
     ORDER BY date_sent DESC LIMIT 10
 ) A
 ORDER BY date_sent";
```

Comment: but wouldn't this return the latest message first? i need the latest message to be the last row...

Answer (score 5):

LIMIT limits the result set, and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS counts the number of rows that would have been returned without the LIMIT.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM messages
WHERE thread_id = :thread_id
ORDER BY date_sent DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Then use [`mysql_num_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

Let's avoid the loop altogether:

```
$threadIds = array(100,101,102); // etc

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE thread_id IN (".implode(',', $threadIds).") ORDER BY date_sent DESC LIMIT 10");
```

That should work.  Note that this *might* be less efficient depending on your data model and the amount of data you're working with.

**EDIT**

This will give you the OVERALL most recent 10.  If you need the most recent 10 for each `thread_id`, check out RolandoMySQLDBA's answer.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Order the dates the other way around?

"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE thread_id='".$thread_id."' ORDER BY date_sent DESC LIMIT ".$number_of_results

Answer (score 0):

Rolando is right. You must order records backward and after this limit results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select * From 
  (Select top(10) * From Messages Where threadid = ? order by date_sent desc) dummyName
Order By date_sent asc
```

I think.